# Eclipse Che Debug the Extension

Tags: eclipse-che

I want to define my own extension for that I am learning existing extension plugin from https://github.com/eclipse/che/tree/master/samples/sample-plugin-json.

How to debug the Eclipse Che Plugin from Eclipse?

I can attach remote debugger to workspace agent server and port but debug pointer doesn't get hit, any pointer will be helpful?

Comment: I am also facing this problem. And since extension is running inside docker, I am not sure whether it is possible to debug through docker container.

Comment: @ Zhao: I found the anwer, please chek below answer, it helped for me.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Che deploy the extension to wsagent. For every wsagent we get new port.

If we switch to "Operation Perspective", we can see the wsagent debug port.  From IDE/eclipse, we need to remotely connect to this port.

[image: Operation Perspective]

We need to listent to that port in IDE:
[image]

By following above steps, our extension gets the call.